# process unexpectedly exit , AAPT2 errors

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aapt2

The actual problem is that the syncing process is going great without any errors.But after sync was successful when i try to build the app, there are 2 errors shown:

```
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

AAPT2 aapt2-4.2.0-alpha04-6589975-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
```

Process unexpectedly exit.

Please, help me out to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help

[Various bug reports](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=%22Windows%20Universal%20C%20Runtime%22) mention that installing Windows Universal C Runtime manually helps. See if that helps.

Download: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Comment: I tried to i stall tha windows universal c runtime but ot is given for upto windows 8 and also it is said that universal c runtime is install defaultly in windows 10....also it isn't issue of runtime as i can execute the aapt2.exe through cmd.....please suggest another solution if possible